# How to prevent redirects in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, http, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using CapserJS 1.1.0-beta3 combined with PhantomJS 1.8.2.

I call an url which respond with a redirect (HTTP 302). PhantomJS automatically follows the redirect, but in my usecase PhantomJS should not follow the redirect.

The debug output of the redirect looks like:

```
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://foo.com/bar.jsp, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
```

How can I configure PhantomJS/CapserJS to not follow redirects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a little workaround necessary. So you need to first identify which URL is the redirect. With [`resource.received`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-received) you receive the response to the first request which contains the URL where it should be redirected to. But we can't do anything from this event handler. We therefore save the target URL which is identified as a redirect target for later.

Now the underlying headless browser (PhantomJS or SlimerJS) follows the redirect by requesting the new resource, but now [`resource.requested`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-requested) provides us with the tools to abort the request (sadly this is not documented in CasperJS). So the final script looks like this:

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

var redirectURLs = [],
    doLog = true;

casper.on("resource.requested", function(requestData, networkRequest){
    if (doLog) console.log('Request (#' + requestData.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(requestData) + "\n");
    if (redirectURLs.indexOf(requestData.url) !== -1) {
        // this is a redirect url
        networkRequest.abort();
    }
});

casper.on("resource.received", function(response){
    if (doLog) console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response) + "\n");
    if (response.status === 301) { // use your status here
        redirectURLs.push(response.redirectURL);
    }
});

casper.start("https://stackoverflow.com/q/27021176").run(function(){
    this.echo("DONE");
    this.exit();
});
```

This is adapted from my answer [A: How to configure Poltergeist or PhantomJS to not follow redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809652)

You could do the same as with the linked PhantomJS version directly in CasperJS by exchanging `page` for `casper.page`, but CasperJS has a few advantages. You can add multiple handlers to the same events with the `casper.on` notation and most all you can decide if all resources are treated the same way or just page loads. So you can exchange `resource.received` for [`page.resource.received`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-received) and `resource.requested` for [`page.resource.requested`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-received).

Comment: Thank you! I've run your script with CasperJS but networkRequest.abort() doesn't work. The argument networkRequest seems to be undefined.

Comment: That seems to be because of you old version of PhantomJS (I just tried it out). I don't know from which version on this works. I strongly advise you to update to a newer version like 1.9.8